# Is this query using indexes, in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I'm not sure if this query is using indexes or not.
How do I tell?

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT au.* FROM users au WHERE au.id IN(SELECT fa.from_user_id FROM approvals fa INNER JOIN personas pp ON fa.persona_id = pp.id WHERE fa.to_user_id=1 AND pp.is_foundation=1 GROUP BY fa.from_user_id) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 9999999999;
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys         | key        | key_len | ref                | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | au    | index  | NULL                  | PRIMARY    | 4       | NULL               | 2272 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | fa    | ref    | to_user_id,persona_id | to_user_id | 4       | const              |  396 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pp    | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY    | 4       | kjdb.fa.persona_id |    1 | Using where                                  |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `key` column in the output indicates the index that MySQL is using.

So yes, the query uses indexes.

You can read a lot more about the output of `EXPLAIN` in the MySQL documentation for the version of MySQL you are running. For example, if you're running MySQL 5.1, read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html.

Comment: WHy does it take 3 seconds to run this query  if it's using indexes?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be quick. Yes, for joins, but not to filter records. Please take a look on Extra field. it should be "using index" while it's *using where* which is indeed slower.

Please consider to revise query to avoid subqueries.

Comment: I think `Using index` means that it's using the index as a covering index. `Using where` does mean it's using the index for the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @Trott.

Though I think you quite capable and able to formulate and try the alternative queries, 
still, one weird fact of MySQL (easily overseen): MySQL claims since long, that an EXISTS can be better optimized than a IN SELECT, as the sought element then is inside the subquery.

That would be in its simplest form:

```
EXPLAIN
  SELECT au.*
  FROM users au
  WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT fa.from_user_id FROM approvals fa
    INNER JOIN personas pp ON fa.persona_id = pp.id
    WHERE fa.from_user_id = au.id
      AND fa.to_user_id=1 AND pp.is_foundation=1
    GROUP BY fa.from_user_id)
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 0, 9999999999;
```